# Поиск натуральных чисел

Tags: c++

> Найти 15 первых натуральных чисел, делящихся нацело на 19 и находящихся в интервале, левая граница которого равна 100. В С++ Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поиск первых 15 чисел делящихся на 19 без остатка в интервале, левая граница которого 100.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int k = 100 / 19 + 1;
    for ( int i = k; i < k + 15; i++ )
        std::cout << 19*i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Несколько более сложное решение, нежели предыдущее:

```
const double max_num = std::numeric_limits< double >::max();
const double epsilon = std::numeric_limits< double >::epsilon();
const double divider = 19.;
std::vector< double > targets_numbers;
for (double num = 100.; (num < max_num) && (targets_numbers.size() < 16); num++)
{
  const double reminder = num % divider;
  if ( fabs(reminder)  <= epsilon )
    targets_numbers.push_back( num );
}
```

Comment: а что, к double переменным применим инкремент?

Comment: да, применим.

Comment: а деление по модулю?